# Output a file in two columns in BASH

Tags: bash

I'd like to rearrange a file in two columns after the nth line.

For example, say I have a file like this here:

```
This is a bunch
of text
that I'd like to print
as two
columns starting
at line number 7
and separated by four spaces.
Here are some
more lines so I can
demonstrate
what I'm talking about.
```

And I'd like to print it out like this:

```
This is a bunch           and separated by four spaces.
of text                   Here are some
that I'd like to print    more lines so I can
as two                    demonstrate
columns starting          what I'm talking about.
at line number 7
```

How could I do that with a bash command or function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you chatraed and BRPocock (and your colleague).  Your answers helped me think up this solution, which answers my need.

```
function make_cols
{
     file=$1         # input file
     line=$2         # line to break at
     pad=$(($3-1))   # spaces between cols - 1

     len=$( wc -l < $file )
     max=$(( $( wc -L < <(head -$(( line - 1 )) $file ) ) + $pad ))

     SAVEIFS=$IFS;IFS=$(echo -en "\n\b")

     paste -d" " <( for l in $( cat <(head -$(( line - 1 )) $file ) )
           do
                printf "%-""$max""s\n" $l
           done ) \
           <(tail -$(( len - line + 1 )) $file )

     IFS=$SAVEIFS
}

make_cols tmp1 7 4
```

Answer (score 4):

Actually, `pr` can do almost exactly this:

```
pr --output-tabs=' 1' -2 -t tmp1
```

↓

```
This is a bunch                     and separated by four spaces.
of text                             Here are some
that I'd like to print              more lines so I can
as two                              demonstrate
columns starting                    what I'm talking about.
at line number 7
```

`-2` for two columns; `-t` to omit page headers; and without the `--output-tabs=' 1'`, it'll insert a tab for every 8 spaces it added. You can also set the page width and length (if your actual files are much longer than 100 lines); check out `man pr` for some options.

If you're fixed upon “four spaces more than the longest line on the left,” then perhaps you might have to use something a bit more complex;

The following works with your test input, but is getting to the point where the correct answer would be, “just use Perl, already;”

```
#!/bin/sh
infile=${1:-tmp1}
longest=$(longest=0;
          head -n $(( $( wc -l $infile | cut -d ' ' -f 1 ) / 2 )) $infile | \
              while read line
              do
                  current="$( echo $line | wc -c | cut -d ' ' -f 1 )"
                  if [ $current -gt $longest ]
                  then
                      echo $current
                      longest=$current
                  fi
              done | tail -n 1 )
pr -t -2 -w$(( $longest * 2 + 6 )) --output-tabs=' 1' $infile
```

↓

```
This is a bunch           and separated by four spa
of text                   Here are some
that I'd like to print    more lines so I can
as two                    demonstrate
columns starting          what I'm talking about.
at line number 7
```

… re-reading your question, I wonder if you meant that you were going to literally specify the `nth line` to the program, in which case, neither of the above will work unless that line happens to be halfway down.

Comment: Coworker suggests that my silly `while` sub-process might be rewritten into a “map; sort; tail” model pipeline that may be less complicated. The `tail` is there because the modified version of `longest` is in the subprocess created by the pipe. If anybody feels strongly about it, I can try re-writing it to pass through `sort -n` rather than wrangling temp vars, but I suspect the difference is really trivial.

Answer (score 0):

Could be optimized in many ways, but does its job as requested.

Input data (configurable):

1. file
2. num of rows borrowed from file for the first column
3. num of spaces between columns

**format.sh**:

```
#!/bin/bash

file=$1
if [[ ! -f $file ]]; then
    echo "File not found!"
    exit 1
fi

spaces_col1_col2=4
rows_col1=6
rows_col2=$(($(cat $file | wc -l) - $rows_col1))

IFS=$'\n'
ar1=($(head -$rows_col1 $file))
ar2=($(tail -$rows_col2 $file))

maxlen_col1=0
for i in "${ar1[@]}"; do
    if [[ $maxlen_col1 -lt ${#i} ]]; then
        maxlen_col1=${#i}
    fi
done
maxlen_col1=$(($maxlen_col1+$spaces_col1_col2))

if [[ $rows_col1 -lt $rows_col2 ]]; then
    rows=$rows_col2
else
    rows=$rows_col1
fi

ar=()
for i in $(seq 0 $(($rows-1))); do
    line=$(printf "%-${maxlen_col1}s\n" ${ar1[$i]})
    line="$line${ar2[$i]}"
    ar+=("$line")
done

printf '%s\n' "${ar[@]}"
```

**Output:**

```
$ > bash format.sh myfile
This is a bunch           and separated by four spaces.
of text                   Here are some
that I'd like to print    more lines so I can
as two                    demonstrate
columns starting          what I'm talking about.
at line number 7
$ >
```